# Replace names with serial number using Spacy Python

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to replace the names in a text a dataframe (two columns: Name and Comments) with serial numbers. To do so, I am using Spacy's NeuralCoref for the NER. My current code is only good enough to replace the names in the dataframe with "[REDACTED]".

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd
`Load the large English NLP model`
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg-2.1.0')

`load neural coref to Spacy pipe`
 import neuralcoref
 neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)

df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\XXX\YYY\try.xlsx')

def replace_name_with_index(token):
if token.ent_iob != 0 and token.ent_type_ == "PERSON":

    return "[REDACTED] "

else:
    return token.string

def scrub(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    for ent in doc.ents:
       ent.merge()
    tokens = map(replace_name_with_index, doc)
    return "".join(tokens)

for ind in df.index:
    name = df['Name'][ind]
    comments = df['Comments'][ind]
    textDoc = name + " ; " + comments #concat text from both columns
    #remove stopwords and punctuations
    print (scrub(textDoc), end = '\n')
    print("---")
```

I am trying another set of codes in an attempt to replace the names with index numbers first.

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd


# Load the large English NLP model
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg-2.1.0')

#load neural coref to Spacy's pipe
import neuralcoref
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)

text= "Carolina Smith Henderson is my sister. Carolina Smith Henderson is a dog lover. Carolina loves to eat ice cream even though she is lactose intolerent. She has a brother named Andrew and a sister named Brenda"

doc = nlp(text)

newString = text
index = 0

for e in reversed(doc.ents): #reversed to not modify the offsets of other entities when substituting
    start = e.start_char
    end = start + len(e.text)
    #newString = newString[:start] + e.label_ + newString[end:]

    newString = newString[:start] + str(index) + newString[end:]

    index = index + 1

print(newString)
```

But the problem with the above code is that "Carolina Smith Henderson", "Carolina Smith Henderson" (2nd mention) and "Carolina" is considered as 3 different "PERSON" though they are referring to the same person. Could you kindly advise how the code could be improved such that the NeuralCoref could identify it as one individual and only assign one index to it? Subsequently, this is to be done for all the records in the dataframe using for loop as shown in the first half of the post.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: replace all `"Carolina"` with `"Carolina Smith Henderson"`

Comment: But there could be "Carolina Oliver Stone" in the new few records, thus its not exactly feasible either

Comment: maybe first replace `"Carolina Smith Henderson"` with `"CarolinaSmithHenderson"`, next `"Carolina Oliver Stone"` with `"CarolinaOliverStone"` and finally `"Carolina"` with `"CarolinaSmithHenderson"`. Always start with longer strings.